# Value label for variable

Tags: r, r-factor

I want to attach a value label to the variables (0 = "Male" and  1 = "Female") in my data frame.

I tried this:

```
CB$gender <- factor(CB$gender, levels = c(0,1), labels = c("Male", "Female"))
```

But I get this result:

```
[1]  Female Male   Male   Male   Female Female Male   Female Female Male   
     Male   Male   Male   Male  
[15] Male   Female Female Male   Female Female Male   Male   Male   Female 
     Male   Female Male   Male  
[29] Male   Female Female Male
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite know what is wrong but splitting it apart like this seemed to work

```
 gender<-c("Male","Female","Male","Female")

 gender <- as.factor(gender)

 levels(gender)<-c(0,1)
```

Of course, pay attention to the fact I used my own made up data.

So try to subset the data first

```
gender<-CB$gender
```

And then apply the above. Best of luck!